# Regular Expression to split 'VS Teamnames' string 

Tags: javascript, regex

I have scraped titles from [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com) videos. Which I have reduced to strings similar to these:

```
string1 = "Red~VS~Blue";
string2 = "oRange v wHite";
string3 = "black knights verses purple people";
```

---

```
team0 = string.split(regexp)[0];
team1 = string.split(regexp)[1];
```

I am trying to use Javascript's `string.split` method to break up each string into an array of two teamnames. It doesn't matter if spaces or delimiters get through, as they can be easily cleaned later. I also want the regexps to have some basic typo catching functionality.

Regular Expressions:

```
regexp = /\Wv(s|\W)/i; \\Should match " v " or " vs", gives 3 results instead of 2
regexp = /\Wv[s\W]/i; \\Works as I thought the above should 
regexp = /\W(vs|v\W|vers[eu]s)/i \\attempt at dealing with typos, doesn't work
```

When I add more parenthesis `()` instead of encasing whatever I've written, it tends to add extra results to the split. I've read these tutorials on regexps [here](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) and a few answers on [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) but I can't find anything relevant to help me. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result = subject.split(/\W+v(?:ers[ue])?s?\W+/i);
```

correctly splits all your example strings.

**Explanation:**

```
\W+        # Match one or more non-word characters
v          # Match v
(?:        # followed by
 ers[ue]   # ersu or erse
)?         # (optionally)
s?         # followed by s (optionally)
\W+        # Match one or more non-word characters
```

This also matches `versu` or `verse`, though.

Comment: Thanks! Matching verse would be a positive and versu is unlikely to be input, Is ?: equivalent to ?= and )? equivalent to )* ?

Comment: @Crazometer: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, so it works just like plain `(...)` but does not store the contents of the match for later reuse ("backreference") and is therefore faster. I just noticed that the outer pair is redundant, though; I will clean that up right now.